# Sage: graphics are plotted on the wrong X11 display

Tags: matplotlib, xorg, sage

I set up a sage server by adding the following line to my ~/.profile:

```
nohup sage -c "notebook(interface='', secure=True, automatic_login=False, directory='./sage_notebook.sagenb')" >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

I run my sage server from an Ubuntu desktop.

When I login and try to plot graphics from my laptop, the figures appear on my desktop screen.

I tried looking for solutions to this online, but I could not find anything.

Comment: this might do better on super user as this is really a system configuration issue, not a programming issue.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that this was caused by setting SAGE_PATH to python's site-packages.

In hindsight, I realize this probably overwrote Sage's built in graphics libraries and caused the graphs to be plotted from the computer that started sage.